# Using multiple databases for a web application that allows independent profiles

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, pdo

I have a web application where companies can register their company and use a set of features. However, lets say `company 1` and `company 2` has registered. They are still accessing the same website. Now each of these companies are 100% independent of each other when it comes to sharing information etc. The only thing they **might** share, is the **users/employees**.

Now my question is really, what is the best practice if each of these companies are to `insert`, `select`, `update` and `deleted` about 10K rows a day, each.

It can be everything from project handling, hourlists etc. All of which are split into different tables.

Would it be best practice to have independent databases, or use the same database for all the companies, and identify them by `company_id`?

Also keeping in mind the web application has to easily adapt to more than 10+ companies.

Comment: If "users" are shared between companies, you might be divulging info that you should not.

Comment: @RickJames the only information that is being shared is the users Full name, e-mail, account number and CV. Things that would be required for all employees in all companies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go one of two ways:

1. Add a `companyId` column to your tables,
2. Create a separate database for each company.

**Option 1:**
This option is the most dynamic one. You can keep the data separated by adding the correct `companyId` identifier to the `where` clause of your query.

This method is good when:

- You expect a large number of customers,
- You expect your number of customers to increase and decrease on a regular basis,
- You do **not** need to share your database access with your customers (they only access it through your API/GUI).

**Option 2:**
This option gives a better separation of data. You keep each custommers data in their own dedicated instance of the database schema. This option allows you to offload the access-control burden to the database server, instead of having to enforce it in your application logic (which is more error prone).

However, there are some downsides: whenever a new customer shows up, you need to create a new database instance for them, which implies having a user with create database and grant privileges, something not every system administrator would be overly happy about.
The other issue is that whenever something changes in the database structure, you need to apply the chance to each instance of the database.

The good thing about this option is that you can give backup copies of your database to your customers, give them direct access to the database server, if needs be, or, in a more limited form, you could give them a copy of the database structure, without the need to filter out the `customerId` columns (as would be the case with *option 1* above).

**In summary:**
There is no silver bullet, it all depends on your use-case. *Option 1* is more flexible, *Options 2* offers a better separation of data and easier access management.

Comment: Great explanation Jacco! Kudos for this. From what you have said, I agree with Option 1. I dont really want the customers to be able to access the database themselves. Also if they do need an export of the database. This can be done creating a query. Whilst, working the other way around, it would be a lot harder to maintain. However, how many rows can a standard database table handle? Lets say its autoincrement with Big Int.

Comment: With an `BIGINT unsigned`, you have room for 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 (18.4 quintillion) possible records. By coparison, there are 'only' 7,400,000,000 ([7.4 billion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population)) people on our planet. I wouldn't worry about reaching this limit anytime soon (or later for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

[1]Keep separate database as there is more DML operations with your database.

[2]Keep very good database maintenance plan for Statistics management, Index maintenance and Backup/Recovery,otherwise you will have performance issue or more down time in case of database crash.

Comment: Are these two alternatives or should I use both? Also, do you have any documentation or speed test to refer to?

Comment: You should implement both to have optimum uptime of your website, Unfortunately I don't have documentation.